# Check if inside errorhandler in before_request

Tags: flask

In Flask, is there a way to check which error from `errorhandler` triggered `before_request` to be executed?

I want to avoid querying the database for users in 500 error pages in case it's a database-related error. Currently, I have a setup like this:

```
from flask import request, g, app
from my_app import db, generate_my_sitemap

skip_load_user = set()

@app.before_request
def load_user():
    g.user = None

    if request.endpoint in skip_load_user:
        return

    if "user_id" in session:
        g.user = db.session.get(session["user_id"])

def add_to_skip_load_user(view):
    skip_load_user.add(view.__name__)
    return view

@app.route('/sitemap.xml')
@add_to_skip_load_user
def my_view_without_auth():
    return generate_my_sitemap()

@app.errorhandler(404)
@app.errorhandler(500)
@add_to_skip_load_user
def http_errors(error):
    return render_template('http_error.html')
```

I noticed that in a 404 error handler, `endpoint` is `None`, so it's possible to do this:

```
if not request.endpoint:
   return
```

However, I only want to make an exception for 500 error pages, not 404 error pages. Is there a way to check if `before_request` was triggered by a 500 `errorhandler`?

Edit: I did a workaround by not loading user `if endpoint is None` on `before_request`, and then calling the function explicitly on `error_handler`

```
@app.before_request
def load_user():
    ...
    if request.endpoint is None:
        return
    ...

@app.errorhandler(404)
@app.errorhandler(500)
def http_errors(error):
    if getattr(error, 'code', None) == 404:
        load_user()
    ...
```